# Display MySQL query result in Wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I want to display a counter on my Wordpress homepage.  The counter is a SUM of numbers in a column.  I tried using the Wordpress plugin JellyFish Counter but couldn't get it to work.  I was able to edit the static numbers of the plugin but couldn't figure out how to get it to display the variable's number.  I tested out this code by placing it in the page.php file. It works when I echo the $weight variable.

How can I display this result on my Wordpress homepage?  Do I need to create a shortcode?  If so, how do I create a shortcode for this

```
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "";

 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

 $sql = "SELECT SUM(weight) FROM users";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
 $weight = $row['SUM(weight)'];

 $conn->close();
```

Comment: what do you mean how to display? `echo` ?

Comment: In one of the CMS pages I'd like to display the sum of the weight column.  I'm wondering if I'm going to have to just create my own php page instead of using shortcode in the CMS page.

Comment: it depends, that decision is up to you, just choose where you are comfortable with

Answer (score 0):

you can create a short code save html with data in a single text variable and return it.
like.

```
add_shortcode('all_news', 'test_plugin_allNews');
    function test_plugin_allNews(){

            $result = //Query Result
            $text = "<ul>";
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                foreach($row as $col)
                {
                    $text.= "<li>". $col ."</li>";
                }
            }
            return $text."</ul>";
        }
```